# Finding adjacent edge in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to implement the 2 opt technique to optimally solve the travelling salesman problem. I have learnt that starting from an edge, I have to find it's adjacent edges and select an edge from them to carry out next step. But my question is: what is the meaning of this adjacent edge? What is the procedure of finding this adjacent edge?

[image]

For example: If I select the edge AD, what will be it's adjacent edges?
I have read a paper, where It's been said that the only adjacent edge is BE. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Two edges are *defined* to be adjacent if they share a vertex.

Comment: From pg. 11 of the [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKz7Tr2prMAhVPI44KHdIQBq4QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.indstate.edu%2F~zeeshan%2Faman.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFsFiLh2EKDeohduW_kh84bdkDxjA) you hid in the comments below, "We should now select an edge such that it is **not** adjacent to the edge being considered, AD. Here, we only [sic] one such edge, BE." (emphasis mine) Apparently at that point in the execution of the algorithm, they are only considering edges `AB`, `DE` and `BE`. `AB` and `DE` are obviously adjacent.

Comment: you have said "Apparently at that point in the execution of the algorithm, they are only considering edges AB, DE and BE" why are these edges to be considered? can you please explain the reason? @beaker

Comment: No, because I'm not going to read your paper for you. I simply went by the text I quoted and the image where those edges were highlighted below it.

Comment: What are the adjacent edges of Ad in the figure if we want to find it normally? @beaker

Comment: You've already been given the definition by @j_random_hacker above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I would say that your adjacent edges would be the edges that touch A or D such as AF,  AB,  AC, AE, DE...

Comment: I have read a paper, where It's been said that the only adjacent edge is BE @Quico Llinares Llorens

Comment: @user6149854 could you share your paper, or say what explicitly says?

Comment: [here is the link of the paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKz7Tr2prMAhVPI44KHdIQBq4QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.indstate.edu%2F~zeeshan%2Faman.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFsFiLh2EKDeohduW_kh84bdkDxjA) @Quico Llinares Llorens

Comment: @user6149854 
Let G=(V,E) be a digraph.

Two arcs e1,e2∈E of G adjacent if there exists a vertex v∈V to which they are both incident. I think adjacent is what I said you before.
Here is the link. 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Adjacent_(Graph_Theory)/Edges

Comment: according to this, will the adjacent edge of AD be BE? @Quico Llinares Llorens

Comment: @user6149854 according to this nope.

Answer (score 0):

**How to find the adjacent edge?** That depends on how the edges are stored. Two popular ways:

- Adjacency List: Here the adjacent edges are in the list itself.
- Adjacency Matrix: Here the adjacent edges exist between those vertices where the value in the matrix[row][col] is non-zero/true.

Comment: If I select the edge AD, what will be it's adjacent edges? @displayName

Comment: @user6149854: The graph you have given is a weighted graph. It is stored as a 2D matrix of ints where each value represents the weight. In absence of an edge, you put -1. For edge AD, the adjacent edges will be DB, DC, DE, DF along with the edge DA because the graph is undirected.